# Do currencies that are invested on belong to real assets or financial assets?

Tags: currency, investing

When considering investments in currency, I wonder if currency belongs to real assets or financial assets, and why? Thanks!

Note: I learned that assets are divided into real assets and financial assets from [Bodie's textbook "Investments"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073530700).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currencies are a financial asset.  Real assets must have a productive capacity.  That is, they must be able to produce a good or service.  Currencies, in contrast, are actually liabilities of the issuing government.  In the case of the US Dollar, each paper bill is marked as a "[Federal Reserve Note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Reserve_Note)" which makes it clear that

> Legally, they are liabilities of the Federal Reserve Banks and obligations of the United States government.

Comment: Thanks! So currencies are financial asset, but are they financial instrument?